# Умный builder в Java

Tags: java, build

Для своей библиотеки решил использовать паттерн билдера. Каким образом можно полностью защитить структуру от вылетов приложения, связанных с ее настройкой? Например, вот, мне нужно, чтобы можно было вызвать только метод `centerCrop()` или `centerInside()`, но не оба сразу

```
Giffy.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .size(gif_container.getWidth(), gif_container.getHeight())
    .centerCrop()
    .centerInside() //ошибка на этапе компиляции
    .loop(true)
    .show(gif_container);
```

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите при наличии в билдере вызовов centerCrop() и centerInside() вызывать ошибку компиляции?

Comment: @gil9red, именно так. Я пока думаю просто сделать подбилдеры, чтобы при вызове `centerCrop()` не было доступа к `centerInside()`, но, блин, методы вызываться могут в разном порядке, при вызове `centerInside()` надо чтобы не было доступа к `centerCrop()`, наверное, тогда придется в ридми это описать. Мне интересно как лучше сделать, чтобы все красиво было :)

Comment: Кстати, возможно, что вообще ни `centerCrop()` ни `centerInside()` не будет вызван

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В качестве альтернативы предложил бы объединить два метода в один, который принимает перечисление:

```
Giffy.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .size(gif_container.getWidth(), gif_container.getHeight())
    .center(CenterType.CROP)
    .loop(true)
    .show(gif_container);
```

Чтобы методы нельзя было вызвать, нужно возвращать типы, в которых таких методов нет. Приходит в голову решение с цепочкой билдеров:

```
interface BaseBuilder {         
    BaseBuilder load(String url);
    //...остальные методы ...
    CropBuilder centerCrop();
    InsideBuilder centerInside();
}

interface CropBuilder {
    CropBuilder loop(boolean isLoop);
}

interface InsideBuilder {
    InsideBuilder loop(boolean isLoop);
}
```

Т.о. методы `center***` возвращают типы, у которых методов `center***` нет. Это повлияет на последовательность вызовов, так что возможно потребуется вынести все общие методы в отдельный интерфейс, от которого наследовать все остальные билдеры.

Comment: Ну да, примерно так я и представлял :D Вот только не очень удачный пример привел, типы центрирования можно вынести в константы, да. А как быть именно с методами?

Comment: @Flippy пример как раз по методам. Суть в том, что метод возвращает другой билдер у которого не объявлены «запрещенные» методы.

Comment: Ооооой, извините, спасибо большое!